# REST method's won't PUT or POST to the server

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get some REST methods working in my Spring app but seem to be running into little success. I'm obviously missing something but I can't tell for the life of me what it would be. Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProvisionService provisionService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/home/data", method=RequestMethod.GET,
                    headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Provision> getData() {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = null;

        if(principal instanceof UserDetails)
            username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();

        return provisionService.getAllByUser(username);
    }

    //JSON put request - doesn't work currently
    @RequestMapping(value="/home/data", method=RequestMethod.PUT,
                    headers="Content-Type=application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void updateProvisions(@RequestBody List<Provision> provisions) {
        log.info("Provisions: " + provisions.toString());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/","/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void showIndex() {}
}
```

Here is the main part of JSP that utilizes it:

```
<sf:form id="homeForm" method="put" action="${homeData_url}"></sf:form>
```

The form is submitted through Javascript when the user clicks on a button. Anyway, things work fine for the GET. I get Json returned with my List of objects, no problems. I then display that using Dojo and so far so good. However, when I try to return the Json with this form I'm getting a 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported error. As you can see I've got the method handler in my Controller so I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've taken those handler's out of the Spring in Action 3 book and it also resembles what some Spring docs and stuff say to do, but obviously I'm missing a key component. Anyone have any thoughts?

I do have the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` mapped in my web.xml which is why I'm using the Spring form tag.

Anyway, any thoughts or help are appreciated. Thank you.

**------------------UPDATE------------------**

Here are the headers after I click on the button and get the 405 error, if it helps:

```
http://localhost:8080/NFI/home

POST /NFI/home HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/NFI/home
Cookie: JSESSIONID=584AC21ADE4F214904B9E7E2370363EF
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, PUT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1085
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2011 15:39:26 GMT
```

Comment: >However, when I try to return the Json with this form I'm getting a 405... How exactly looks the request that you send.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `headers="Content Type=application/json"` constraint?

Comment: @Ralph No, same result. Besides isn't that necessary so that it knows it's getting the Json object and can decode it?

Comment: The Json Request to "/home/data." does it really contains the paramter to change the Method (HiddenHttpMethodFilter)?  Please check this with some tool or set a beakpoint within `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`

Comment: When I examine the source of the JSP it does indeed create a hidden input with the appropriate values. So yes I'm assuming it does. However, I'm not getting into the method back on the server side to be able to evaluate any further than that.

Comment: use some Firefox plugin (http live headers) to check what is really send to the server.

Comment: The header doesn't seem to include anything relating to HttpMethodFilter. I'll list what it includes above but I don't see anything relevant. Perhaps I'm not properly sending the Json object back?

Comment: not even that there is no `_method` parameter there is even no content at all!

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a Form is done using POST. You get a "POST" not supported error.

Above, I see you are using a RequestMethod.PUT in your source code. There's no mention of POST at all.

Comment: That's part of what Spring does for you. Because I'm using the HiddenHttpMethodFilter and Spring Form tags, it handles that part for me. The form is rendered using POST with a hidden value of PUT and Spring translates it for you. I shouldn't need a handler looking for POST. Regardless, I thought of that and did try changing my RequestMethod to POST but I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add you need to add a parameter `_method` with value `PUT` to your request. Not to the json content!

So in the first step I would change requested URL to `/home/data?_method=PUT`.

If this work you can search for an way how to add the `_method` parameter to the request content without disturbing the Json data.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do anything. I'm pretty sure that because of Spring and the HiddenHttpMethodFilter, _method is already in the Request. But I gave it a shot and received the exact same problem. Thanks for the thought though. It does seem odd to me that I'm not somehow sending back the Json object, but in none of the examples do I seem them doing anymore than I did.

Comment: @cardician: may you have several problems, but the HiddenHttpMethodFilter can not do anything if you do not submit the `_method` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You updated your question with the headers, could you also put the entire request out there (actual dumped values) to see the _method parameter(s) being sent?

Also, while I guess the headers=""-rules are valid they shouldn't be needed. You have a json converter bean that will do marshall and unmarshall based on content-type and accept headers, if no valid converter is found Spring will return an error.

The only reason to include it in the @RequestMapping would be if you had a method that actually did something else if you called it with xml instead of json and that sounds like a bad design.

Remove those header-rules and try again, make it as simple as possible and gradually add logic.